# Exporting parameters from RSA provider takes long time in monodevelop c#

Tags: c#, mono, cryptography, rsa, monodevelop

I carried my RSA encryption method to MonoDevelop project. It already was working, but in mono
ExportParameters() function takes 4-5 minute. I can't understand it. Thanks for your helps.

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

RSAParameters rsaPar = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the answer in the [source code of RSACryptoServiceProvider](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Cryptography/RSACryptoServiceProvider.cs) class:

```
public RSACryptoServiceProvider ()
    : this (1024)
{
    // Here it's not clear if we need to generate a keypair
    // (note: MS implementation generates a keypair in this case).
    // However we:
    // (a) often use this constructor to import an existing keypair.
    // (b) take a LOT of time to generate the RSA keypair
    // So we'll generate the keypair only when (and if) it's being
    // used (or exported). This should save us a lot of time (at 
    // least in the unit tests).
}
```

As you can see ExportParameters() method is performing RSA keypair generation which is time consuming operation. How much time it actually takes depends on the type of [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) used and whether there is enough [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28computing%29) available on your system to seed it.

Comment: 4-5 minutes for generating a 1024 bit RSA key-pair is insane.